# The bean 'postRepository', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a simple blog backend in spring boot as a personal project. I am doing this as a part of trying to pick up some Java Spring and I'm having issues with the code below (there's quite a bit...).

The error I'm getting is exactly this: **The bean 'postRepository', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.**

The code itself worked fine initially as I used Hibernate, I had 2 DAOs, 2 DAOImpls and used those within the service classes to make calls to the DB and back. Everything worked as expected - full list of users can be returned, full list of posts can be returned, individual user/post, etc. All crud operations.

If I understand correctly, to switch over to Spring Data JPA all I need is to get rid of `DAO` and `DAOImplementations` and just have one interface per entity that extends `JpaRepository<T, T>` which would provide implementations for findById,findAll, save, delete to name a few. However, after making the change, deleting the `DAO` and `DAOImplementations` and then updating the ServiceImplementations, I am getting the above error. Here are the entity classes:

**Post Class:**

```java
package com.me.website.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
public class Post {
    //fields of the Post object
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name="author")
    private String author;
    @Column(name="date")
    private LocalDateTime date;
    @Column(name="excerpt")
    private String excerpt;
    @Column(name="featured_media")
    private byte[] featuredMedia;
    @Column(name="content")
    private String content;
    @Column(name="category")
    private String category;

    //constructor for the Post object
    public Post(String title, String author, LocalDateTime date, String excerpt, byte[] featuredMedia, String content, String category) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.date = date;
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
        this.featuredMedia = featuredMedia;
        this.content = content;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Post() {}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", author=" + author +
                ", date=" + date +
                ", excerpt='" + excerpt + '\'' +
                ", featuredMedia=" + Arrays.toString(featuredMedia) +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' +
                ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    //getters and setters
```

**User Class**

```java
package com.me.website.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name="display_name")
    private String displayName;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String displayName, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", displayName='" + displayName + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

//getters and setters
```

**DAO using Spring Data JPA**

```java
package com.me.website.dao;

public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {
    //no implementation required
}
```

```
package com.psyonik.website.dao;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    //no implementation required
}
```

**Post/UserService**

```java
package com.me.website.service;

public interface PostService {
    public List<Post> findAll();
    public Post findById(int theId);
    public void save(Post thePost);
    public void deleteById(int theId);
}

package com.me.website.service;

public interface UserService {
    public List<User> findAll();
    public User findById(int theId);
    public void save(User theUser);
    public void deleteById(int theId);
}
```

**Service Implementations**

```java
package com.me.website.service;

@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PostServiceImpl(PostRepository thePostRepository) {
        postRepository=thePostRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Post> findAll() {
        return postRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Post findById(int theId) {
        Post thePost = null;
        Optional<Post> byId = postRepository.findById(theId);
        if (byId.isPresent()) {
            thePost = byId.get();
        }
        return thePost;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Post thePost) {
        postRepository.save(thePost);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        postRepository.deleteById(theId);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.me.website.service;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(int theId) {
        User theUser = null;
        Optional<User> thisUser = userRepository.findById(theId);
        if (thisUser.isPresent()) {
            theUser = thisUser.get();
        }
        return theUser;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User theUser) {
        userRepository.save(theUser);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        userRepository.deleteById(theId);
    }
}
```

**The POST Rest Controller**

```java
package com.me.website.restcontroller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PostRESTController {
    private PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    public PostRESTController(PostService thePostService) {

        postService = thePostService;
    }


    /*GET mapping - this one returns a list of all the posts =========================================================*/
    @GetMapping("/blog")
    public List<Post> findAll() {
        return postService.findAll();
    }


    /*GET mapping - this provides a pathvariable for a postId to retrieve a particular post item or return an error ==*/
    @GetMapping("/blog/{postId}")
    public Post findById(@PathVariable int postId) {
        Post post = postService.findById(postId);
        if (post == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Post not found " + postId);
        }
        else return post;
    }


    /*POST mapping - this creates a new blogpost object and saving it to the db ======================================*/
    @PostMapping("/blog")
    public Post addPost(@RequestBody Post thePost) {
        //in case an id is passed, this will be converted to 0 to force an insert instead of an update
        thePost.setId(0);
        postService.save(thePost);
        return thePost;
    }


    /*PUT mapping - this updates a given blog post given the id passed through =======================================*/
    @PutMapping("/blog")
    public Post updatePost(@RequestBody Post thePost) {
        postService.savePost(thePost);
        return thePost;
    }


    /*DELETE mapping - this is to delete a specific blog post item ===================================================*/
    @DeleteMapping("/blog/{blogId}")
    public String deletePost(@PathVariable int blogId) {
        //retrieve the correct post
        Post thePost = postService.findById(blogId);
        //throw exception if null
        if (thePost == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This post doesn't exist in db. Post ID: " + blogId);
        }
        else {
            postService.deleteById(blogId);
        }
        return "Deleted post with id: " + blogId;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.me.website;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsiteApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsiteApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have removed the import statements as everything looks fine...

I'm just not getting why this is happening. I was thinking that maybe the spring bean factory is trying to make more than one post repository beans, but there's no reason for it...

I thought maybe I just missed the configuration (but that's not the case since the main method from the spring boot project has `@SpringBootApplication` which takes care of all of that).

I then thought that I need to add `@Transactional` on the `JpaRepository` interfaces, but that's not the case either if I understood that correctly from the Spring Boot Data documentation... Would I need to set bean name properties for the two JpaRepository interfaces?

If so, why? :) Wouldn't the constructors use the name of the classes which is different (PostRepository vs UserRepository)?

Answer (score 2):

Neither suggestion helped, as in Spring boot as I mentioned before and now researched as well, you don't really need either `@Repository` or use `@EnableJpaRepositories("package.name")` as `@SpringBootApplication` does all the scanning for you as long as your repositories are within the same package. IF you have one repository in one package for one entity and another package for another entity and another repository, you would need to use this qualifier to ensure packages are scanned correctly.

The fix was actually entirely unintuitive - my pom.xml still had reference to `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` which was causing issues. After commenting it out, this got resolved.

For anyone who wants to be able to see the difference from the first to the edited version, you can check my github [here](https://github.com/Catalin-M/Website/tree/master/website-spring-data-jpa). The database is MySQL and its setup with 2 tables, one called post and one called user running locally. Hope it helps someone in the future :) Thank you for the answers.